# Simple use of QNAM causes memory leak

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

According to valgrind, the following code has a memory leak.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    network_manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    do_stuff();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete network_manager; // <-------- Removing this line fixes the leak
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::do_stuff()
{
    connect(network_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(process_stuff(QNetworkReply*)));

    request.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.com/"));
    network_manager->get(request);
}

void MainWindow::process_stuff(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qDebug() << reply->readAll();
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

I create a QNetworkAccessManager object, and I delete it manually when the destructor gets called. But, if I remove the delete call the memory leak goes away. I don't understand this, because according to the [Qt model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html) I should only not call delete if I pass the ownership:
`new QNetworkAccessManager(this);` But still, even passing the ownership, the memory leak still happens (removing or not the delete).

Is it a false positive, or I'm not seeing something?

Comment: Are you running valgrind directly, or under Analyze perspective of Qt Creator?

Comment: @hyde I'm using the Analyze of Qt Creator. Running valgrind directly, gives me a lot of errors, even if it is a "empty" application.

Comment: Yep, without suppression file valgrind may give a lot of false positives from some libraries, which is why I asked how you run it. I think it's still false positive. But why don't you give `network_manager` parent, if you create it in constructor and delete in destructor?

Comment: @hyde I would give it a parent, the problem is that, according to valgrind, it still leaks memory. The only way that valgrind does not detect a memory leak, is if I do NOT give it a parent and also NOT delete the object, which makes no sense to me. It must be a false positive.